# Generalized pythagoras' theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

In these notes:
http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/resource/general/115a.3.02f/week9.pdf

at the end of page 3, a proof is provided. 
He says by induction we know that:
$\left \| v_2+...+v_{n-1} \right \|^{2}=\left \| v_2 \right \|^{2}+...+\left \|v_{n-1} \right \|^{2}$

Shouldn't it be:
$\left \| v_1+...+v_{n-1} \right \|^{2}=\left \| v_1 \right \|^{2}+...+\left \|v_{n-1} \right \|^{2}$ instead?

Are we even allowed to start at whatever $v_i$ just as long as we have less than $n-1$ vectors in our induction hypothesis step?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a typo.

Comment: Well, I suppose that you're correct that it should be $\left \| v_1+...+v_{n-1} \right \|^{2}=\left \| v_1 \right \|^{2}+...+\left \|v_{n-1} \right \|^{2}$ instead. Probably a mistype I'd say.

Comment: @LionelRicci thank you!

Comment: @BigbearZzz thank you!

Comment: But in general, does writing the norm of the sum starting at $v_2$ or $v_3$ until $n-1$ and writing it as the sum of the norms infringe our induction hypothesis?

Comment: The induction step is on the number of orthogonal vectors, not on their labeling or anything else. What's in the notes does not violate the hypothesis.

Comment: @LionelRicci Awesome! Thank you so much, you cleared a confusion about recursion that I had so please feel free to write your comment as an answer so I can choose it as best.